# ui-router: update parent from a child

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a question about ui-router and it architecture.

What is the best way to update parent template or something like this?

if I have two states:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('layout', {
    controller: 'LayoutCtrl as layout',
    templateUrl: 'app/layout/templates/layout.html'
  })
  .state('layout.page', {
    controller: 'PageController as page',
    templateUrl: 'app/page/templates/page.html'
  });
```

and a template `layout.html`:

```
<header>
   <h2>{{ layout.title }}</h2>
</header>
<ui-view></ui-view>
<footer>
    <!-- some content -->
</footer>
```

How can I set a page title (layout.title) ?

Or I have a problem with a specific page. On this page I have a fixed layout header. How I can make a fixed layout header? I have a directive named `sticky`, what is the best way to tell a parent state to set this directive to header?

I'm using `$scope.$emit` and `$scope.$on` for this but I'm not sure is this a correct way. Thank you.

Comment: To update `layout.title`, you can modify it from the controller of child state, given that it is wrapped by controller of parent

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `$rootScope` attribute to handle the page title and modify it in my underlying controllers.